# Why is the select menu not working in Mac terminal?

Tags: bash, select, terminal, menu, macos-sonoma

I was trying to create a menu in using select but alas the menu won't accept my answers and won't also let me quit the menu. I tried this:

code:

```
options=( "olá" "adeus" )
echo "escolha uma opção"
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case opt in 
        "olá")
            echo "Olá de volta!"
            break
        ;;
        "adeus")
            echo "Mal criado chunga!"
            break
        ;;
    esac
done
```

This was the test in the terminal:

```
Last login: Wed Oct 11 10:27:23 on ttys000

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
(base) Luiss-MacBook-Pro:\~ luiscunha$ sh teste2.sh
escolha uma opção

1) olá
2) adeus
   \#? 1
   \#? 2
   \#? olá
   \#? 1)
   \#? 1) olá
   \#?
```

Comment: the select command is not supported in all shells, so you need to use a shell that supports it, such as bash,you can add this to the top of your script: `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: It still does the same thing, even after placing ´´´ #!/bin/bash ´´´ on top of my script.

Comment: Instead of using `sh teste2.sh`, try using `bash teste2.sh` to run the script.

Comment: `case opt in` -- missing `$` for the variable: `case $opt in`

Comment: Also, as demonstrated below, use PS3 for the select prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save this script to a file, for example `my_menu.sh`, and then run it using `bash my_menu.sh`.

check this out :

```
#!/bin/bash

options=("olá" "adeus")
PS3="Escolha uma opção: "

select opt in "${options[@]}"; do
    case $REPLY in
        1)
            echo "Olá de volta!"
            break
            ;;
        2)
            echo "Mal criado chunga!"
            break
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Opção inválida. Tente novamente."
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: It's kind of working now, except now it always falls in the * option, echoing "Opção inválida. Tente novamente.", even if my answer is 1 or 2.

Comment: Yes, the **value** is stored in opt ("olá") but the **number** is stored in REPLY (1)

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working now! Done what you said btw!